# Formulas in Springer format with pandoc markdown

Tags: markdown, pandoc

Is there a particular 'markdown' phrase that will place a formula in the middle of the page, also with a number to the side, as required in the Springer format?

I'm a beginner in using any kind of markdown and am currently writing a paper in the Springer format. I don't know how markdown really works (maybe as a bonus someone can link me a good website? i haven't found any concise explanations) but I've been recommended to work by writing a .Rmd file in RStudio and then convert it to pdf with pandoc.

This whole markdown stuff seems to be really bad documented (or i really don't know where to look)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Pandoc's markdown is [documented here](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/README.html#pandocs-markdown). However, the PDF generation is actually done with LaTeX, so you'll have to use a [template](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/README.html#templates) that does what you want.